“psloglist” for system event returns an error: -1073740940
My batch must extract system and application events.
I use two psloglist (vers. 2.82) cmd one after the other.
psloglist \\Home  -d 7 -f we sys > system.log
psloglist \\Home  -d 7 -f we app > application.log

The first psloglist return error: -1073740940 the second 0.

Are you actually running dos?

I cannot reproduce this - working fine here.

Journeyman Geek yes this is a DOS batch
